# Node JS VPN connect to endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I hope you can help!

I have setup and Amazon echo applcation, the application makes a request to and AWS EC2 instance and gets JSON data as a response, this is working as expected however the use case for the final application is to connect to a private IP sending paramaters to an API to return the same JSON DATA.

for many reasons sadly I cannot share any of the endpoint information.

I need my NODE.js Application to make a request to the private IP over a VPN connection, Im currently using OPENVPN to make local requests to the endpoint.

I have looked at node packages to see if this is possible but I cannot seem to find one, except for this package here

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-openvpn

```
This package is has a dependancy thats fails to download, so i got the node_module manually but Im getting an error when i try to execute the code 


var openvpnmanager = require('node-openvpn');

var opts = {
    host: 'xx.xx.xx.xx', // normally '127.0.0.1', will default to if undefined
    port: 443, //port openvpn management console
    timeout: 1500, //timeout for connection - optional, will default to 1500ms if undefined
    logpath: 'log.txt' //optional write openvpn console output to file, can be relative path or absolute
};

var auth = {
    user: '*******',
    pass: '*******',
};

var openvpn = openvpnmanager.connect(opts)

openvpn.on('connected', function() { //will be emited on successful interfacing with openvpn instance
    openvpnmanager.authorize(auth);
});

openvpn.on('console-output', function(output) { //emits console output of openvpn instance as a line
    console.log(output)
});

openvpn.on('state-change', function(state) { //emits console output of openvpn state as a array
    console.log(output)
});

// openvpnmanager.getLog(console.log) //get all console logs up to this point

// and finally when/if you want to
// openvpnmanager.disconnect();

openvpn.on('disconnected', function() { //emits on disconnect
    openvpnmanager.destroy() //finally destroy the disconnected manager
});
```

this just gives me an error

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'writable' of undefined
            at Telnet.exec (C:\Users\user\Desktop\alexa-    po\node_modules\node-openvpn\node_modules\telnet-client\lib\telnet-    client.js:90:24)
```

If anybody has any suggetions on how to make this possible I would be very grateful.